# How open a pygame console terminal through SSH (JuiceSSH)?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh, lxterminal, pygame

I have made a piece of code with pygame on the Raspberry Pi and I want to run it through the Android app JuiceSSH so I can use it on my Android phone. But whenever I run it on my phone, even with 'sudo', it returns an error 'unable to open a console terminal'

Is there any possible way to open a terminal on my Android phone so the pygame graphic console terminal will pop up?

(I have seen other similar questions/answer but they do not help with this situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JuiceSSH is an SSH client which in its free version offers only shell (text) access.

JuiceSSH Pro - a paid version of this app - allows X11 forwarding and integrates with an [X Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.XServer) app.

Refer to the [How to tunnel X over SSH using Port Forwarding](http://sonelli.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/182200-how-to-tunnel-x-over-ssh-using-port-forwarding) guide.

On Raspberry Pi side you need to ensure `ForwardX11 yes` option is set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

And then you need to add an environment variable `DISPLAY` before running your program.

---

As a side note, [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) SSH client for Android seems to support X11 forwarding and it's free.

Comment: hi, thanks, but on the website it says to enter an address. do it type 'ssh.myxdomain.com' literally or is there something else that is suppose to go there?

Comment: It must be an address of your Raspberry Pi - either a DNS name, or the IP address.